# JSON Response in ASP

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, json

I'm a PHP Developer and have no knowledge about asp. I'm developing a portal in PHP and need to do an ajax post to an asp page(external server) and the response it sends is something like this:

```
OK|some_id|some_name|some_id|0|1|||some_name|some_email|some_address|some_street|some_city|some_zipcode|some_country|date|0|-
```

The values are separated by "|", which is too complicated to process.

I have the access to the asp code. The code looks as follows.

```
Set con01 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con01.Open "some_db"
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql = "some_query"
rs.Open sql,con01,1,1,1

If NOT rs.EOF THEN
    Response.Write "OK" & "|"
    Response.Write rs("memTableUniID") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("memID") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("memPassword") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("webMaster") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("belongsGroupID") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("prefix") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("foreName") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("familyName") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("eMail") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("homeAdd") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("homeCity") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("state") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("zipPostal") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("country") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("registerDate") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("startFrom1to3") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("oldSN") & "|"
    Response.Write rs("nameOnCert") & "|"

    Set rsSub = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    sql2 = "another_query"
    rsSub.Open sql2,con01
    If NOT rsSub.EOF THEN
        Response.Write "MOK" & "|"
        Response.Write rsSub("canAccess") & "|"
        Response.Write rsSub("usedCode") & "|"
        Response.Write rsSub("usedTimes") & "|"
        Response.Write rsSub("canReg") & "|"
        Response.Write rsSub("usedReg")
    Else
        Response.Write "MIS"
    End If
    rsSub.Close
Else
    Response.Write "RNF"
End If

rs.Close
con01.Close
```

How can I change the response to JSON object or if that is too complicated to change in asp, is there an easy way to parse the response string to JSON using javascript?

Comment: To produce JSON on the ASP side you would create an object with appropriate property names and then use the .NET equivalent of `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to take the response as it currently is, split it via "|" using a regular expression `preg_split` and then json encode the resulting array.

```
var myString = "OK|some_id|some_name|some_id|0|1|||some_name|some_email|some_address|some_street|some_city|some_zipcode|some_country|date|0|-";

var myArray = myString.split(/\|/);

var myJson = JSON.stringify(myArray);

console.log(myJson);
```

**edit:** The code below is PHP, because you tagged this as PHP. I missed the fact that you cannot do this in PHP. The idea would be the same, but do it with JavaScript

```
$string = "OK|some_id|some_name|some_id|0|1|||some_name|some_email|some_address|some_street|some_city|some_zipcode|some_country|date|0|-";

$array = preg_split("/\|/", $string);

$json = json_encode($array);

print_r($json);
```

Comment: Hi Luke, thank you for solutions. I was looking more of an asp solution, as I can easily process the response from PHP side. But I wanted a solution for long term perspective which helps the future developers too. My colleague solved the issue by changing the asp code.